# contactListener does not work , how to implement it?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection, game-physics

I am trying to implement the method beginContact contactlistener class , but I have some doubts about it .
I'm new to libgdx and I can not figure out how to " leave" the method that controls the contacts .
in my project I have a Stage that manages the actors .
I looked online and found that I have to add World .
but I can not understand the concept , why :)

Some good soul can help me? Thank You

```
   public void create() {
    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,-10), true);
    world.setContactListener(contactlistener);

    //meteora
    meteora = new Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("planet.png")), 128, 128));
    meteora.setOrigin(meteora.getWidth() / 2, meteora.getHeight() / 2);
    meteora.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, 100);
    meteora.setZIndex(3);


    group = new Group();
    group.addActor(spaceShip);
    group.addActor(flagShip);
    group.setZIndex(3);
    group.setWidth(98);
    group.setHeight(128);
    group.setOrigin(group.getWidth() / 2, group.getHeight() / 2);
    group.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    stage.addActor(group);
    stage.addActor(meteora);
}

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
    /*....other code....*/
}

ContactListener contactlistener = new ContactListener() {
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
        final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();

        System.out.println(x1.getUserData());
        System.out.println(x2.getUserData());

        if ( (x1.equals("gruppo") && x2.equals("planet")) || (x1.equals("planet") && x2.equals("gruppo")) )
            System.out.println("shot");
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {

    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `Actor` and subclasses are classes from `Scene2D`, the Libgdx scenegraph, while `World` and `ContactListener` are form `Box2D`, a physics engine.
The `Box2D` engine can't work with `Actor`s, it needs `Body`s and `Fixture`s to work.
So if you want to use both concepts together, you need to create a `Box2DActor`, which creates a `Body` inside it's constructor and adds it to the physics `World`.
The in your `render(delta)` you need to update the `World` using it's `step` method and then you need to update the `Box2DActor`s positions, using the positions of their `Body`s.
I suggest you to read those articles in the libgdx wiki:

- [Scen2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)
- [Box2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d)

It won't be a bad idea to read the rest of the wiki or at least the for you relevant parts.
Also i suggest to start with much simpler games, which does not need a physics engine like `Box2D`, to get some basic knowledge of libgdx.
Starting with complex games will just frustrate you, as you will face many problems down the road and many of them will be hard to solve.

**EDIT:**
The collission detection itself depends on the shapes you are using.
If your objects are circles, then they collide, if the distance between them is smaller then the sum of their radii.
For `Rectangle`s you could use the `overlaps` method.
The `Intersector` class does also contain a few methods to detect collisions/overlaps of different objects.
The management is another thing. If you don't have to many and to complex objects, i guess it would be enough to keep them in a list and iterate through it in a nested `for` loop, checking every object pair.
A little optimization would be to do a distance check before the actual collision check, as most object will be sorted out, before doing some complex overlap checks.

Comment: How can I detect collision so without box2d ? Is there a way ? I tried the overlaps and it works , but with dynamic objects it does not work .